# Qmessagebox not working

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmessagebox

I'm using Ubuntu linux. I've used pyuic4 command and created a .py file and then added a messagebox to it.Here it is:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 200, 98, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 640, 25))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.about)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def about(self):
    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Test", "This is a test.")

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After experimenting a lot I found that it works if I change this:
 `class Ui_MainWindow(object):`
 to this: 
`class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):`

I made a big script and I don't know if it will cause any problem or if I'm doing the right
thing .I'm just confused. Please help and pardon me if there's any problem in my writing.
This is my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the result of pyuic4 in the same way. In fact I would not use pyuic4 at all, but let's see the possibilities:

### Using pyuic4

Say you have your ui file `my_window.ui` in which you create a `QMainWindow` widget named `MainWindow`. With Designer, you also added a link between the `clicked` action of the push button and a custom slot `about()` (do you know how to create a custom slot in designer ?). Now using the ui file can be done in 2 steps:

1. You generate the python equivalent file `ui_my_window.py` with `pyuic4`:

   ```
   $ pyuic4 my_window.ui -o ui_my_window.py
   ```
2. Then you create another python file (main.py) which will import the file `ui_my_window.py`. **Do not modify the file generated by pyuic4 !** It will be overwritten if you rerun the `pyuic4` command !

   ```
   $ cat main.py

   from PyQt4 import QtGui
   # import the class created py pyuic4
   from ui_my_window import Ui_MainWindow

   class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self, parent=None)
       QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
       self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)

       # Beware that all widgets are now available through the self.ui attribute
       # Getting the push button is written:
       # self.ui.pushButton

     def about(self):
       # this is the custom slot created in Designer
       QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Test", "This is a test.")

   if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
     myMainWindow = MyMainWindow()
     myMainWindow.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

So now you have 3 files:

```
      $ ls
      main.py ui_my_window.py my_window.ui
```

Just run `python main.py` to launch the GUI.

### Without using pyuic4

PyQt4 provides a very usefull module when working with ui files: the [uic module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#the-uic-module). In fact pyuic4 is using this module to generate the python file of the ui file. Using the module allows you to avoid the pyuic4 step (**Beware:** if you use icons in a resource file (.qrc), you still need to use the `pyrcc4` tool and import the resulting file in your code).

In your example, the code becomes very light:

```
$ cat main.py

import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui
# import the uic module
from PyQt4 import uic

class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None)
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    # Load the ui file
    uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"my_window.ui"), self)

    # Now in this case, all widgets can directly be accessed because the last argument
    # of loadUi is self.
    # Getting the push button is written:
    # self.pushButton

  def about(self):
    # this is the custom slot created in Designer
    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Test", "This is a test.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myMainWindow = MyMainWindow()
  myMainWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this case you just have 2 files:

```
      $ ls
      main.py my_window.ui
```

Again just run `python main.py` to launch the GUI.

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation. Actually, in stead of "pyuic4 my_window.ui -o ui_my_window.py", I use this command: "pyuic4 -x my_window.ui -o ui_my_window.py".

Comment: But the problem is this: "class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):" 
when I need to have this "class MyMainWindow(object):" 
so that I can easily use Qmessagebox.Will it be wrong if I 
manually replace "object" with "QtGui.QMainWindow"? 
And I don't know how to create a custom slot in designer. 
Please let me know it.

Comment: The option `-x` generates a executable python script, but in the case I presented, it will not work because the method `about` does not exist yet.

To add a custom slot from designer, right click in the MainWindow and choose "Modify signals/slots" or something similar (sorry my version is not in English). A window will appear allowing you to add custom signals and slots to your main widget. If you connect a signal to a custom slot, don't forget to implement the slot in the inherited widget, like I did in the example

Comment: Thank you Frodon. Actually, I make executable python script at first.
Then I edit the script and add my necessary functions and manage signals and
slots. This is easier for me. I don't have to write too many things.

Comment: By using the 2nd method (without pyuic4), you don't have much to write ;)

Comment: I followed you instructions and got this error message:
"AttributeError: 'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'about' "
Is there any problem in this line:
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), MainWindow.about)

Comment: Which instructions did you try ? The one using pyuic4 ?

Comment: I was able to call a window using the second method
but didn't get the button.
Can you find any mistake here:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = MyMainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: Ok I understand, this is my mistake: some lines were missing in my code. Please recheck my answer: I added the `if name == "main"` part.

Comment: Great ! Thanks Frodon. Both the methods are working now. I've learnt many things today.